ProtectedPermissions Status Reset After FOTA Updates for App Preloads
We have an app that's preloaded into OEM devices. After a FOTA update, certain permissions that were pre-granted (e.g., ACCESS_NOTIFICATION) are reset and un-granted, even though they were granted during the preload process. Question is whether the resetting of ProtectedPermissions is a standard behavior after FOTA updates or if it is an issue related to specific OEMs or device configurations or whether we can do something to be able to regrant them automatically?
